# Did Draco's wand choose him, or was it chosen for him?

Tags: harry-potter

It is a somewhat common saying, when referring to Harry Potter, that the wand chooses the wizard. Indeed, Ollivander says this twice when Harry buys his wand. So it is curious that when Harry meets Dracro in the shop *Madam Malkin’s Robes for All Occasions*, Draco says:

> 'My father’s next door buying my books and mother’s up the
>   street looking at wands,’ said the boy. He had a bored, drawling
>   voice. ‘Then I’m going to drag them off to look at racing brooms.'

Now of course Draco's mother could have been looking at wands for herself, or maybe she just liked to look at them. Too, Draco may have already been in possession of his wand. But in context, it sounds rather like Draco's mother is buying his wand for him. So assuming that the context says what it implies, did Draco's wand chose him, as Harry's did it's owner, or was Draco's wand chosen for him by his mother?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think Draco's wand chose him, although I do see what you're saying about parsing the language. Draco demonstrated throughout the series that he knew exactly what he wanted, that he wanted the best, and that second-hand supplies and clothing were unacceptable. For example, Draco got all new clothes and robes, a Nimbus 2001, the Hand of Glory, and weekly boxes of sweets and treats from home. I would imagine Draco would have pitched a fit if he himself didn't get to be choosen by the perfect wand. Further, in *Deathly Hallows*, he was extremely motivated to get his wand back from Harry after Harry won it from him, to the point that he follows Harry into the Room of Requirement.

> ‘That’s my wand you’re holding, Potter,’ said Malfoy, pointing his own through the gap between Crabbe and Goyle.
>   ‘Not any more,’ panted Harry, tightening his grip on the hawthorn wand. ‘Winners, keepers, Malfoy. Who’s lent you theirs?’
>   ‘My mother,’ said Draco.
>   <sub>*Deathly Hallows* - page 505 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 31, *The Battle of Hogwarts*</sub>

Draco's wand served him well, which indicates, I think, that he and his wand were paired up nicely. Draco, for all his faults, did show some formidable skill in spell casting and duelling.

I think if Draco was using an heirloom wand or a wand just picked out for him by his Mummy, his skill would not have been as strong. Both Neville and Ron, who had hand-me-down wands, did much better at magic when they were able to get a new wand, a wand that chose them individually. According to [POTTERMORE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dUdW.jpg), unicorn tail hair wand cores -- which Draco's is -- tend to form a very strong and loyal bond with their owners and are difficult to sway their allegiance to a new owner. Also, interestingly, wands with a unicorn tail hair are the *least* likely to turn to the Dark Arts, and we all know that in the end Draco was unable to stomach being a Death Eater.

Answer (score 10):

"Looking at wands" is not the same as "buying me a wand". Plus as you say it is only implied that she is looking at a wand for him, maybe she needed a new one herself. In any case it seems fairly obvious from *The Deathly Hallows* that Draco's wand chose him.

Harry recognizes that of the wands that they collected at the Malfoy Manor, Draco's is the one that works best for him. (Implying that he *won its allegiance* from its owner).

The best piece of evidence however, is when Harry finds out that it is Draco's wand that he has from Ollivander:

> “Hawthorn and unicorn hair. Ten inches precisely. Reasonably
>   springy. **This was the wand of Draco Malfoy.**”

Ollivander then goes on to explain to Harry how the wand chooses the wizard. It seems unreasonable for him to unequivocally tell Harry that the wand belonged to Draco and then explain that the wand chooses the wizard, if Draco had not been in the shop himself looking for a wand.

Comment: There would be, no doubt, fittings and findings that would have no effect on the wand *as a wand*, but might elevate it considerably as a personal possession. This would be similar to choosing a watch movement (the wand) for its utility, then choosing the case, face, hands suitable to your tastes and station.

Answer (score 4):

No canon info AFAIR, including on Pottermore.

Remember that Ollievander doesn't try out EVERY wand in the shop on Harry, just a smaller selection **picked by him**.

Quite possible that he could pick a selection of "higher class" wands - approved by Narcissa - based on info about Draco and then let one of them choose Draco half an hour later.

Comment: Ollivander probably has a very good idea on what wand is likely to be suitable for a wizard.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to **Slytherincess's** excellent answer, I think people also tend to presume, incorrectly, that there is one and only one wand that will choose you, kind of like a soul mate sort of thing.

The books, however, have multiple examples of witches and wizards obtaining new wands and willingly giving away their old wands. Also, those who unwillingly lose their wands are able to gain others that work just as well for them.

Like Harry, I would personally be disinclined to do such a thing, but it does happen. I cannot imagine that any wizard would willingly give up one wand for another unless it was at least as comfortable and capable as the first.

Hence, it is entirely possible for multiple wands to choose a witch or wizard, just as different people may choose (feel comfortable with) a wand.